# How to change the color of my side margins not the bottom one or top ones

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So i have to remake the html/css layout of this page:
[image]

What im trying to replicate atm are the grey borders on the html page. i was able to get the borders by adding this code:

```
html {
    background-color: #D4D2DB;
}
body {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

But now when i go to a page where there is little to no text i get a huge grey area at the bottom of the page. Is there a way for me to always load the body to the bottom of the page or is it better for me to type something else in my own css file or in the bootstrap css file?

Example:
[image]

My _ViewStart html code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <div class="headerclass">
        <img class="logotest" src="~/Content/Fotos/logo.png" />
    </div>


    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <link href="~/Content/CSS/StyleSheetLayout.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">
<ul>

    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Index" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "About" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Contact" ? "active" : "")">@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
</ul>
</div></div></div>
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr/>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

My css code looks like this:

```
.headerclass {
    max-width: 1280px;
    min-width: 768px;
    background-color: #ffffff;



}

.logotest {
    margin-top: -2%;
    width: 85px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 17%;
    margin-bottom: 1.5%;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
     border-top: solid 1px;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: rgb(110,110,120);
        text-align: center;
        padding: 13px 50px;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-right: solid 1px;
    }

        li a:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #0099cc;

        }
.active {


    background: #0099CC;
    color: #ffffff;

}
.active a{

    color: #ffffff;
}
    .active a:hover {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
html {
    background-color: #D4D2DB;
}
body {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=body+min+height+cover+full+screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the height of `body` to the full height of the window

Add this to your CSS

```
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This worked. Will accept your asnwer as soon as it lets met. Thank you